# Salesforce APEX Fetching Name of an Account record by its Id without SOQL

Tags: salesforce, apex

In my APEX trigger, I have Id of the account but I need to pull also Name and Phone of that account.
I can write SOQL and get that info but I was wondering if there is another way without SOQL.

I tried below but it does not work because get() is a non-static method.

```
        Id newId = Id.valueOf(SfAccountId);
        String accountName = Account.get(newId).Name;
```

Comment: Why do you need it without query? Is it about 100 Soqls limit? Concerns about data visibility, sharing rules? You could pull something query-less with platform cache for example but I'd do it as optimisation last resort, it's not really right use of the tool

Answer (score 0):

"It depends".

If you're sure you need only Account Name and Phone - you could create formula fields for that on your object. These fields should be available OK even in a `before insert` trigger - but only if the Account lookup is mandatory and on the page layout. You're here kind of piggybacking on Salesforce's "order of execution" and what checks it runs even before it hits your trigger.

For me it always felt bit hacky, too close to relying on.. well, not undocumented behaviour but something fishy. If it talks about page layouts - how it will behave when there's no UI (integrations? background batch jobs?). https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/198487/799

You could call [`Formula.recalculateFormulas(records)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Formula.htm#apex_System_Formula_recalculateFormulas) and it'll waste a SOQL if it has to.

If you don't want to waste formula fields for this (Name, Phone, what in future?) or are concerned this can break in future - use this pattern to collect the account ids, make 1 query, then 2nd loop to process it. Avoids "SOQL in a loop".

```apex
trigger xyzTrigger on xyz__c(before insert){
    Map<Id, Account> accs = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(xyz__c x : trigger.new){
        accs.put(x.Account__c, null);
    }
    accs.removeKey(null);
    if(!accs.isEmpty()){
        accs.putAll([SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accs.keyset() WITH USER_MODE]);
        for(xyz__c x : trigger.new){
            Account a = accs.get(x.Account__c);
            if(a != null){
                x.Name = a.Name;
                x.Phone__c = a.Phone;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion.
Formula field is definitely solution that would work.

Just for anyone having the same question.
Based on my searches there is no way to pull data by account Id without writing SOQL query. e.g.

```
List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account WHERE Id =: AccountId LIMIT 1];
```

If anyone has idea how, I would love to see it.
Thanks for help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).